# Cakephp3 handle authorization as a plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've been working on cakephp3 for a while now. I've always used [Cakephp's Auth component](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html) for authorization and authentication purpose.

I follow the very conventional procedure every time, like loading the component, adding isAuthorized function in controllers and defining allowMethods etc.

But now what I want is to develop my **own plugin** for this purpose, just using **Cake's Auth component**. So that i can reuse the plugin in all my future projects, also i want it to be like **plug and play**. Like You enable it, add few settings and your **User management** is done.

I know that how migrations work so I can add users table via migration every time. (Just an idea)

The thing I don't get right now is how to make everything separate from the core app? Like everything is done via plugin and nothing is added to every controller of the app.

Hope I'm clear about what I want to achieve.

**Update:** I know there is a whole [list](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#authentication-and-authorization) of third party Auth plugins. But I want to develop my own so i just need the idea of how things work.

Any solutions to my problem would save my day.

Comment: You ask on wrong place, try here  http://discourse.cakephp.org/

Comment: Thanks, I've asked it there as well now.